# Tic Tac Toe in android studio

Tags: android

So as you can guess I am making a game of Tic-Tac-Toe app in android studio.
the question is how can I change the amount of image buttons during run time.
Or maybe is there a clickable grid that I can place and change it size?
The idea is not to limit the game to a 3*3 grid , its to let the user pick what mode he wants.
The java part in which the computer chooses his move is ready , all I need is the design part.
Also how can I change an image with a flip animation?

Comment: And what is the prize?

Comment: Can you be more specific here? Do you want help related to a specific part of the code? Do you want help regarding game design? Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: See this, http://nabinkhadka.hubpages.com/hub/tictactoe

Answer (score -2):

You can use a [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) control to draw your grid. Then you can use the [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to check the location of touch event.

For example:

[image]